# What is the command to display ospatches in Solaris 11?

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

I was using showrev -p until now to get ospatches list. Does anyone have a command for the same in Solaris 11?

Answer (score 2):

There are no OS patches with Solaris 11 (in the sense of SVR4 patches that update individual files in various packages). With [IPS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/o11-083-ips-basics-523756.html), Solaris 11 new packaging way, you just [update packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/o11-018-howto-update-s11-1572261.html) to a new release in an alternate boot environment.

To display packages that have an update available under Solaris 11, you can run the [`pkg list -uv`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21796/pkg-1.html#scrolltoc) command.

Comment: I found this [link](http://quark.humbug.org.au/publications/notes/bofh/msg00015.html) which says `pkginfo` which lists all packages, is it similar to ospatches?

Comment: This link shows a message that predates Solaris 11 by 10 years. The commands summarized there are the one used until Solaris 10. However, it is missing the commands able to list patches, `showrev -p` or `patchadd -p`.